# Proving a language is not Semidecidable

Tags: formal-languages, semi-decidability

I have the language $L = \{ \langle M_1, M_2 \rangle : L(M_1) \subset L(M_2)\}$ and I'd like to prove that it is not Semidecidable. To do so, I need to use a reduction from $\neg H$. I cannot use Rice's theorem. I'm having a hard time with this, and would appreciate a walkthrough.

Comment: Try fixing one of the machines $M_1,M_2$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The entire class is failing, so needless to say none of us are all that prepared in doing this completely on our own. Would really appreciate a walkthrough on this.

Answer (score 1):

Using contradiction suppose $L=\{\left< M_1,M_2 \right>|L(M_1)\subset L(M_2)\}$ is semi-decidable. So there exists Turing machine $T$ which for input $\left<M_1,M_2\right>$ if $L(M_1)\subset L(M_2)$ will halt and accept.

We should use this Turing machine $T$ to make another Turing machine $T'$ which halt and accept on input $\left<w,M\right>$ if $M$  doesn't accept $w$. To do so, you have to make another Turing machine $M'$ using $w$ that you are sure $w\notin L(M')$. Thus you can give $\left< M',M\right>$ as input to $T$ and look for its output. If it accept it means that $L(M')\subset L(M)$ which means $w\notin L(M)$.

[image]

Comment: Im not sure I see the contradiction: youve said T’ halts if M does not accept w, and you conclude with w is not in the language decided by M (if T’ accepts). Aren’t those statements equivalent?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble. We assumed that there exists a "Decidable" Turing machine for $L$ then we were able to make a "Decidable" Turing machine for $HALT^c$ using it. We know that $HALT^c$ isn't decidable so that's the contradiction.